# Inserting data into another field in another table with Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a trigger that inserts a record value into Table1 and also inserts the same value into Table 2. Table 1 and Table 2 have the same columns.

Now i want to insert the value that is in Table 2 into a third table called user fields table, the QNo value in table 2 must be inserted into the alphanumericCol value in Table 3.

> (in terminology terms as follows: trigger after insert on table 1
>   fetches number from table two and derives next number, then inserts
>   new number into table 3 and updates table two with the new number (so
>   that the next time trigger fires it will have the latest number).

Here is my trigger that inserts the number into Table 1 and 2:

```
alter trigger insertQNO
on table1
after insert as
begin
    update Table1
    set QNo ='Q150' + CAST(inserted.Id AS VARCHAR(4)) + '/' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),103),7)
    from Table1
    join inserted on inserted.Id = Table1.ID;

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.table2 ON;  
    insert into Table2 (Id, Qno)
    (select ID, Qno from table1 )

end;
go
```

The results are the same as per the below:

[image]

Now how do i put Qno value from table 2 into Alphanumeric value in user fields table? This is the last part of my trigger but i just cant get it

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014